# AJAX Tab issue for displaying php page in IE8

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="page_1.html">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="page_2.html">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="page_3.html">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="ajax-content">This is default text, which will be replaced</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav li a").click(function() {

        $("#ajax-content").empty().append("<div id='loading'><img src='images/loading.gif' alt='Loading' /></div>");
        $("#nav li a").removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        $.ajax({ url: this.href, success: function(html) {
            $("#ajax-content").empty().append(html);
            }
    });
    return false;
    });

    $("#ajax-content").empty().append("<div id='loading'><img src='images/loading.gif' alt='Loading' /></div>");
      $('#page_1').addClass('current');
    $.ajax({ url: 'page_1.html', success: function(html) {
            $("#ajax-content").empty().append(html);
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

Above code works fine when i use `page_2.html` but when I use `page_2.php` its not working when I use in internet explorer 8.
I don't understand how to fix this.

Comment: Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: yes it is working in other browsers.

Comment: You can try to check the console and the network panel in IE's developer tools and see if there is any error returned from the server or logged to console. Is it possible that you have conditional comments in HTML that target IE8 and change its behavior?

Comment: @AryaMehta (Off-topic) Cool Harp Guitar! I played one a few months ago and loved it, now I want one. lol!

Comment: @AryaMehta Does your `.php` file have a `<!DOCTYPE html>` or just plain `<html>`? Might be the reason.

Comment: I dont think so this issue can be fix so, so is there any way in which I can show a note for IE8 and on tab 'Page 2' click ?

Answer (score 0):

try full url.

`$("#nav li:first a").click();` // insted of repeating code

example that shows AJAX errors in IE:

```
$.post("update.php",{data:"blabla"},function(){
 /*... stuff to do on success...*/
},"json").fail(function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){
 /*... display the errors here so you know what is wrong...*/
 alert(textStatus+": "+errorThrown);
});
```

Comment: full url of `page_2.php` ?

Comment: I dont think so this issue can be fix so, so is there any way in which I can show a note for IE8 and on tab 'Page 2' click ?